# How do static variables behave between multiple targets?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xctest

I'm having a problem with the behavior of a `static` variable defined in global scope in an Objective-C .m file. Specifically, I'm seeing different instances of the object referenced by the same variable from the same code depending on the scope when executing from an XCTest target.

How does a global static variable, defined in a .m file, behave between the main and XCTest targets? Here's an example of the problem I'm seeing:

### Setup Code

**Manager.m**

```
#import "Manager.h"

// This is the variable of interest!
static Manager *sharedManager = nil;

@implementation Manager

+ (instancetype)sharedManager
{
    return sharedManager;
}

+ (void)setManager:(Manager *)manager
{
    sharedManager = manager;
}

@end
```

Here's an extremely simple `ViewController`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    Manager *tempManager = [[Manager alloc] init];
    [Manager setManager:tempManager];
}
```

### The Meat Of The Confusion

I'm attempting to write XCTest unit tests that leverage `Manager`. The thing is, I'm seeing **different** instances of `Manager` from within the same flow of code execution depending on the context of the code. This was totally new and weird to me. For example, consider this unit test:

```
- (void)testManager {
    // 1
    ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];

    // 2
    NSLog(@"manager %@", [Manager sharedManager]);

    Manager *tempManager = [[Manager alloc] init];
    [Manager setManager:tempManager];

    // 3
    NSLog(@"manager %@", [Manager sharedManager]);
    [vc viewDidLoad];

    // 4
    NSLog(@"manager %@", [Manager sharedManager]);
}
```

Here's some observed behavior:

1. Breakpoint pause at line 1. If I `po [Manager sharedManager]` I will see a n object instance with a memory address. I'm assuming that is because `ViewController` is the initial view controller for the project's storyboard, and `viewDidLoad()` creates and sets the first `Manager` shared instance.
2. This line prints **null** to the console, this is weird because a breakpoint and po on **1** showed an actual object in the console.
3. This line prints an actual object instance, but a *different* instance than line 1. What's interesting though is that if I break at this line an `[po Manager sharedManager]` a different object instance is printed than the NSLog at this line prints, but the same instance as printed at the breakpoint at 1.
4. `viewDidLoad()` runs an creates a new `Manager`. Breaking on this line with a `po` shows a new instance, but the `NSLog` prints the same instance as 3.

**Important point** Often the memory address of a `NSLog`'d object is different from the debugger `po`'d object. I don't know why. I'm guessing it is related to how XCTest executes in a different "app" instance?

The behavior I'm observing is that within the same flow of code, access of a `static` global variable within a .m file varies depending on which file is accessing it. Why?

I posted a fully functional, bare bones, project demonstrating this on GitHub at: https://github.com/obuseme/TestStatic

Comment: I'm surprised about 1. However, why don't you implement the usual, thread-safe and well-tested shared instance pattern?

Comment: Good point, this is a simplified example of a constraint I have to work within, which means I can't refactor to the proper singleton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tried recreating the problem by hand in a fresh project, I got:

1. Manager created by loading the initial view controller. (Incidentally, this is a test smell because tests should be in complete control of their environment. For unit tests, I use a [separate application delegate](https://qualitycoding.org/ios-app-delegate-testing/) to prevent this from happening.)
2. The same manager is logged.
3. The `tempmanager`.
4. The manager set by `viewDidLoad`.

This is as expected. Your different results suggests that there's something strange in your project settings. I then downloaded your project and reproduced what you described. An important warning appears in the log:

> objc[5304]: Class Manager is implemented in both /Users/jorei/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BEEDA9FD-5FDA-4347-8691-FD80B8C7A18D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/020A6698-99B6-472A-8E77-330CBCB5AA1A/TestStatic.app/TestStatic and /Users/jorei/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestStatic-clulxcackwiypobvsqvfatqiznvi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestStatic.app/PlugIns/TestStaticTests.xctest/TestStaticTests. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Here's the problem:

[image: Incorrect Target Membership]

There are two occurrences of Manager.m. Each has its own copy of the `sharedManager` static variable.

Comment: Thanks @jon-reid - That's a good catch about the target membership, and was something intentional. Based on how a 3rd party dependency is/was setup for this project, that was a pre-existing condition and something I need to figure out how to work around. I guess the main takeaway here is that a given implementation file should not have membership in multiple targets.

Comment: I just faced this issue and what made it even more difficult to find is that there were no logs because my class was member of a framework and an app extension that depended on the framework. For apps there are logs in Xcode console but not for app extensions.